# Can HTML5 databases and localStorage be shared across subdomains?

Tags: database, html, dns, subdomain, local-storage

I am attempting to share data across subdomains using Safari. I would like to use an HTML5 database (specifically *localStorage* as my data is nothing but key-value pairs).

However, it seems as though data stored to `example.com` can not be accessed from `sub.example.com` (or vice versa). Is there any way to share a single database in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist javascript variables across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981673/persist-javascript-variables-across-pages)

Answer (score 13):

### Update 2016

This [library](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage) from Zendesk worked for me.

Sample:

**Hub**

```
// Config s.t. subdomains can get, but only the root domain can set and del
CrossStorageHub.init([
  {origin: /\.example.com$/,            allow: ['get']},
  {origin: /:\/\/(www\.)?example.com$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del']}
]);
```

Note the `$` for matching the end of the string. The regular expression in the above example will match origins such as `valid.example.com`, but not `invalid.example.com.malicious.com`.

**Client**

```
var storage = new CrossStorageClient('https://store.example.com/hub.html');

storage.onConnect().then(function() {
  return storage.set('newKey', 'foobar');
}).then(function() {
  return storage.get('existingKey', 'newKey');
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log(res.length); // 2
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Handle error
});
```

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788742/5064633

Answer (score 11):

There is simple way to use cross-domain anything, just create simple page that will be included as proxy **iframe** hosted on domain you try to access, send **PostMessage** to that iframe and inside iframe you do your LocalStorage database manipulation. Here is a link to [article that do this with lcoalStorage](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/). And here is [demo that send message to different page in subdomain](http://jcubic.pl/sysend.php) check the source code, it use iframe and PostMessage.

**EDIT**: New [version of sysend.js library](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) (used by above demo) use BroadcastChannel if browser support it, but still it require Iframe. Recent version also simplify using of Cross-Origin messages, you have html of the iframe in repo, that you can use (or you can use simple html file with single script tag with the lib) and in parent you just need to call one function `sysend.proxy('https://example.com');` where example.com need to have `proxy.html` file (you can also use your own filename and different path).

Comment: Is it just me or is that kind of a smelly solution? Sounds kludgey. (No downvote ... just saying).

Comment: It's not really kludgey, as PostMessage was created for the very purpose of communicating across domains. The issue is keeping/maintaining the IFRAME content on the different hosts. Say you're using a 3rd-party shopping cart solution… It's not always possible to create a target page on their domain for your PostMessage receiving IFRAME. Also, look into the new Channel Messaging, which is bidirectional ([support starts at IE10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging,channel-messaging)).

Comment: Probably the best solution of this topic! Native and efficient.

Comment: This is the best general solution for dissimilar domains.  BUT, when you only have subdomains as the OP does, there's a MUCH simpler solution:  You still use the proxy iframe to hold the right origin for data access, but rather than postMessage(), you just set `document.domain = superdomain` on both pages, then they can interact *directly*, and on your main page you then just use `iframe.contentWindow.localStorage` instead of `window.localStorage`!  I guess it's different enough that I'll post it as a seperate answer...

Comment: This solution won't work if "Block third party cookies" setting is on in the browser. It is enabled by default in safari

Comment: @vishesh do you know any other way to send Cross-Domain message on Safari, it seems that nothing will work, unless you're proxy through the server.

Comment: There is no issue in cross domain messaging, issue is getting the message data from local storage in iframes. op wants to specifically read data from local storage. `window.open` might work, but that would require opening and immediately closing the window which might be pretty visible. It also runs the risk of popup blocker

Comment: @vishesh note that when the answer was created, the solution worked in Iframe on Safari, and not don't the same as any other answer. It seems that Safari block any way to sending data out inside iframe, maybe just in case if Advertisers will want to create workaround. I think this should only work with cookies and new FLoC.

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome blocks localStoage access from an iFrame in another domain by default,unless 3rd party cookie is enabled and so does Safari on iPhone...the only solution seems to be opening the parent domain on a different domain and then sending to to the Child via window.postMessage but looks ugly and shifty on phones...

Comment: Is there a setting in Chrome to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes. This is how:

For sharing between subdomains of a given superdomain (e.g. `foo.example.com` vs `bar.example.com` vs `example.com`), there's a technique you can use in that situation. It can be applied to `localStorage`, `IndexedDB`, `SharedWorker`, `BroadcastChannel`, etc, all of which offer shared functionality between same-origin pages, but for some reason don't respect any modification to `document.domain` that would let them use the superdomain as their origin directly.

### NOTE: This technique depends on setting `document.domain` to allow direct communication between iframes on different subdomains. That functionality has now been deprecated. (As of April 2021 it continues to work in all major browsers however. From Chrome v109 the feature will be disabled *unless* an `Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?0` header is also sent.)

### NOTE: Be aware that this technique removes the same-origin defences that block malicious script on a subdomain from affecting the main-domain window, or visa versa, potentially broadening the attack surface for XSS attacks. There are other security implications for shared hosting as well - see [the MDN document.domain page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain#deprecation) for details.

(1) Pick one "main" domain to for the data to belong to: i.e. either `https://foo.example.com` or `https://bar.example.com` or `https://example.com` will hold your localStorage data. Let's say you pick `https://example.com`.

(2) Use localStorage normally for that chosen domain's pages.

(3) On all other *https://*.example.com* pages (the *other* domains), use JavaScript to set `document.domain = "example.com";` (always the superdomain). Then also create a hidden `<iframe>`, and navigate it to *some* page on the chosen `https://example.com` domain (**It doesn't matter *what* page**, as long as you can insert a very little snippet of JavaScript on there. If you're creating the site, just make an empty page specifically for this purpose. If you're writing an extension or a Greasemonkey-style userscript and so don't have any control over pages on the `example.com` server, just pick the most lightweight page you can find and insert your script into it. Some kind of "not found" page would probably be fine).

(4) The script on the hidden iframe page need only (a) set `document.domain = "example.com";`, and (b) notify the parent window when this is done. After that, the parent window can access the iframe window and all its objects without restriction! So the minimal iframe page is something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    document.domain = "example.com";
    window.parent.iframeReady();  // function defined & called on parent window
  </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

If writing a userscript, you might not want to add externally-accessible functions such as `iframeReady()` to your `unsafeWindow`, so instead a better way to notify the main window userscript might be to use a custom event:

```
    window.parent.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("iframeReady"));
```

Which you'd detect by adding a listener for the custom "iframeReady" event to your main page's window.

(NOTE: You need to set document.domain = `example.com` even if the iframe's domain is already `example.com`: Assigning a value to document.domain implicitly sets the origin's *port* to null, and both ports must match for the iframe and its parent to be considered same-origin. See the note here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin)

(5)  Once the hidden iframe has informed its parent window that it's ready, script in the parent window can just use `iframe.contentWindow.localStorage`, `iframe.contentWindow.indexedDB`, `iframe.contentWindow.BroadcastChannel`, `iframe.contentWindow.SharedWorker` instead of `window.localStorage`, `window.indexedDB`, etc. ...and all these objects will be scoped to the chosen `https://example.com` origin - so they'll have the this same shared origin for all of your pages!

The most awkward part of this technique is that you have to wait for the iframe to load before proceeding. So you can't just blithely start using localStorage in your DOMContentLoaded handler, for example. Also you might want to add some error handling to detect if the hidden iframe fails to load correctly.

Obviously, you should also make sure the hidden iframe is not removed or navigated during the lifetime of your page... OTOH I don't know what the result of that would be, but very likely bad things would happen.

And, a caveat: setting/changing `document.domain` can be **blocked** using the `Feature-Policy` header, in which case this technique will not be usable as described.

---

However, there is a significantly more-complicated generalization of this technique, that can't be blocked by `Feature-Policy`, and that also **allows entirely unrelated domains to share data, communications, and shared workers** (i.e. not just subdomains off a common superdomain). @jcubic already described it in their answer, namely:

The general idea is that, just as above, you create a hidden iframe to provide the correct origin for access; but instead of then just grabbing the iframe window's properties directly, you use script inside the iframe to do all of the work, and you communicate between the iframe and your main window only using `postMessage()` and `addEventListener("message",...)`.

This works because `postMessage()` can be used even between different-origin Windows. But it's also significantly more complicated because you have to pass everything through some kind of messaging infrastructure that you create between the iframe and the main window, rather than just using the localStorage, IndexedDB, etc. APIs directly in your main window's code.

Comment: This solution won't work if "Block third party cookies" setting is on in the browser. It is enabled by default in safari

Comment: @vishesh This answer doesn't involve cookies, as such, however it is likely that the Safari setting is blocking other things as well.  It'd be nice to have some more information.  **What doesn't work, precisely?**  Does setting `document.domain` throw an error?  Is access to the iframe from the parent window blocked?  Or does the problem only arise when you try to use localStorage, for example?

Comment: Yes, browsers disable access to local storage just as they do for cookies. This is controlled by the same "Block third party cookies" setting. `document.domain` is deprecated, it might not work in some browsers already. Problem is only when iframe wants to access it's own local storage.

Comment: @vihesh Well if the browser is blocking an iframe from accessing even *its own* local storage, there's not much point asking if you can share access to it across subdomains.  ...Or is it only iframes, and not top-level windows?  Or does it only happen if you change `document.domain`?  In any case, I'll readily concede there are a number of things that can interfere with this solution.  However, when it does work, it can be a lot simpler then the other `postMessage`-based solutions, since uisng it you get direct access to the localStorage/indexedDB/etc APIs.

Comment: @vihesh I'm using it successfully in a Greasemonkey script running on Firefox, BTW.

Comment: @vihesh If the security settings you're talking about are specific to embedded iframes, might you get around it by opening a new window, (instead of using an iframe)?  It's ugly in that the new window would be visible to the user, and you'd have to trust them not to close or navigate it away (or you could detect this and re-open it, provided the pop-up blocker doesn't get you)... but it might be a feasible solution in some cases...?

Comment: This answer correctly acknowledges the deprecation of setting `document.domain`. However, I think it would be really beneficial to readers to enlighten them of the security implications that drove this decision. I would advise inclusion of this in the answer and failing that I would strongly advise any readers to read the deprecation notice on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) before considering attempting an approach like this. It explains well why this usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Colm:  Fair enough. I have added a note to the answer mentioning the security implications.  How important of a consideration this is is going to vary greatly from website to website, obviously.  Usage of subdomains may or may not have been intended as a security mechanism by a site's author.

Comment: Setting `document.domain` is now prohibited within a cross-domain iframe in Chrome, even if it's only cross-site (https://developer.chrome.com/blog/immutable-document-domain/).

Comment: @Abel, according to the article you linked, it's only prohibited by default, and can be re-enabled if the `Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?0` header is sent.