# Can HTML5 Web SQL databases be used across pages?

Tags: html, dns, web-sql

This is probably a very simple question so please forgive my ignorance, but can a Web SQL database be read across pages of the same domain?

For example if I insert data on page mydomain.com/createdata can the same data be queried on mydomain.com/readdata ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: wrt. *subdomains*, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains?rq=1

Comment: (Also, I think IndexedDB is the "endorsed" W3C model... so browser support on Web SQL may be less complete going forward?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's local browser storage then no problem to read this form any page of the same domain. It is designed especially for it. The problem appear when you need to share Web SQL database across different domains, in this case you should deal with [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: I'm Mr. Odiszapc! Odiszapc the Great! Thanks me all! Ha-ha!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Within the same domain is no problem. I believe there is a 5MB limitation on the storage capacity per domain.

For examples and reference code, check [html5Rocks - Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)