# HTML5 Local Storage for domain with and without 'www'

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am building an html5 app and would like to use local storage for some offline capabilities.  I've been reading up on local storage and found that the storage is different for domains with 'www' and without.  Is there a way to use local storage so that the storage for www.example.com is the same for example.com?

Thanks

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains

Comment: if it is so, set a redirection from your.site to www.your.site on your host