# How do I share Firebase Simple Login sessions across domains?

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I have example.com and app.example.com. How can I log someone in from one domain and share that session with the other?

Comment: Can you detail what you've tried so far? Keep in mind that [security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html) can reference data as well as auth creds. So if you write a value into Firebase with the session id and the new user's creds, they can be granted access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Simple Login sessions are persisted using LocalStorage or SessionStorage which are scoped to HTML5 origin, which is a tuple of scheme, host, and port, which is why it is not shared across subdomains by default.

That said, you can manually enable this in your application by creating a shared LocalStorage system, using methods like described here at [Can HTML5 databases and localStorage be shared across subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains?rq=1).

Comment: XAuth hasn't been updated in 4 years, and apparently it doesn't work in modern browsers :\

I think I'll just auth the user through an iframe on the other domain.