# How to store session value in clientside AngularJs Application on reload and redirect happens to new url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJs in my Application.After user login I am storing user name through $window.sessionStorage and redirecting page to new url using $window.location.href ="some url"; But I am not able to get these values in new page load...my code will like this..

In login method

```
$rootScope.userLogged = true;

$window.localStorage.setItem('userLogged', $rootScope.userLogged);

$rootScope.loggedUserName = response.firstName;

$window.localStorage.setItem('loggedUserName', $rootScope.loggedUserName);

$window.location.href = "some url";
```

and in new app run configuration which is going to load after logi...

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', function ($rootScope, $window) {


      if ($window.localStorage.getItem('userLogged') == "true") {


                $rootScope.userLogged = true;
                $rootScope.loggedUserName = $window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUserName');

      }
}]);
```

I used both sessionStorage and localstorage but I am not able to get values properly.

please help me

Comment: `$rootScope.userLogged` is not going to be set on the new page after reload, since Angular app completely reinitialize all the services and scopes after new page load.

Comment: In new page initialization I am not using $rootScope.userLogged,I am trying to get values from $window.localStorage

Comment: Can  you check your localStorage in the browser and see if the values are stored?

Comment: after redirect to new page...its not existing...before redirecting to new page its existed

Comment: yes..both are diffrent...after login it redirects to accountname.domain.com

Comment: That's the problem then.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains