# Is it possible to communicate between pages (tabs) that set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN' with a user-script?

Tags: javascript, iframe

In the context of a user script, for example executed by Tampermonkey, is it possible to communicate between two pages of different domains, which set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'?

I know about [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24349708/5536767) of sending messages from one page to another by using iFrames and `postMessage`, but when working with sites you dont control, like in my case Stack Overflow and Google (working on a bot to automate something for myself), you'll get the `SAMEORIGIN` error when trying to create the iFrame.

But I thought since I'm able to insert script in both pages, it might be possible to pull off some workaround or alternate solution.

One suggestion, a [shared worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) looked promising, but it seems to require the page to be from the same origin. Also I looked at the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API#Browser_compatibility) spec, but it isn't implemented anywhere yet, and it also seems to be bound to the same origin policy.

Another suggested possibility mentioned so far in the comments is to use the [GM API](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php) since this is a user-script (extended / special JS features). With [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_xmlhttpRequest) we can ignore cross domain restrictions and load `google.com`, then put it in an iframe, but all the sources will point to the site where the `iframe` is embedded, so searching the Google page tries to execute the search params on the parent site's domain.

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://www.google.com",
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "Accept": "text/xml"
    },
    onload: function(response) {
        $('html').html('<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>');
        $("#iframe").contents().find('html').html(response.responseText);
});
```

Maybe I could edit the search requests to point to `google.com` specifically, rather than letting the search adopt the parent page's domain. And if that fails due to some hangup with the same origin policy, I could even try to replace Google's `xmlhttpRequest`'s with `GM_xmlhttpRequest`'s, but I'm not sure if that can be done since the user script, if you load GM functions, will run in a sandbox, unable to intertwine with the pages scripts if I understand correctly. I'm just not sure.

On the other hand, if we can trick the `iframe's` contents to treat `google.com` as the domain for requests, though we're in business, but examples don't seem to exist for this kind of thing, so I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it happen.

Comment: Same origin prevent browser from loading page. There is no place to insert your script

Comment: There's always the `GM_*` functions. I believe Tampermonkey supports the ones you would need.

Comment: _"But I thought since I'm able to insert script in both pages"_ If you are able to insert `<script>` into both documents, you can try using `SharedWorker`

Comment: @AlexeyTen They are talking about user-scripts: https://wiki.greasespot.net/User_script

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I know, but user scripts still need document to be loaded

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara see my updates regarding the GM functions. Thanks for the tip by the way, we might be onto something with that.

Comment: Don't worry about the sandbox. First, you're always running in a sandbox. Second, it's mostly there to provide a consistent environment for you (also to expose you the gm_ functions without giving them to the page, I guess). Third, you have access to `unsafeWindow`, which is the page's own global scope, from which you can access almost everything you want - and if you put stuff there, the page will have access to it.

Comment: _"is it possible to communicate between two pages of different domains"_ Not certain what you are trying to achieve? What data are you trying to communicate between two domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, via 2 routes:

1. Since it's a user-script, you have access to special functions known as GM functions. With `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, we can send a request which ignores the same origin policy, allowing us to load the third party page in an iFrame, allowing communication between the frames via `postMessage`. The good thing about this is there's no page reloading, but the bad thing is, you will have to dynamically modify the frame's native `xmlhttpRequest` to execute a `GM_xmlhttpRequest` and specify the full target URL, not just a path such as `/example.js`, otherwise the domain of the outer window will be used in any requests made by the internal frame.
2. We can use URL queries by openning a tab of the same origin as the page you want to communicate with. Then we can use shared web workers to post messages to any previously opened pages of that domain and send the data from the URL query to the page you want. The pros are you don't have to dynamically modify the pages' scripts, but the cons are that you have to open a new tab for each message between different domains.