# Share LocalStorage/SessionStorage between different domains in (angular 6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

in Angular 6, when I stored the data in local storage (localhost:4200) but when we can run a subdomain like(abc.localhost:4200) that time data removed in local storage please help me out this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cross Storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-storage) or [Cross DomainStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-domain-storage)  npms

Answer (score 0):

In short. No.

This is the definition of localStorage specification. [As Mozilla said](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage);

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin;

and there are [some examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin) of what is Document origin.

Answer (score -2):

Data stored to domain.com can not be accessed from sub.domain.com as per the standards. So you cant access local storage of `localhost:4200` from `abc.localhost:4200` no matter what you do. But to overcome this you may use solutions suggested by these posts,

https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/

[Can HTML5 databases and localStorage be shared across subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains)

[use localStorage across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)