# Angularjs not recognising URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am creating a shopping cart using Angularjs 1.5 and localstorage.
 It seems that either Angularjs or the browser does not recognize the same url with or without `www.` as being the same user with the same session, meaning `www.abc.com` is different from `abc.com`.

Is there a way to make Angular recognize `www.abc.com` and `abc.com` as the same session?

Comment: This is not an Angular "issue". Look at this post for e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604754/how-to-create-localstorage-for-the-same-domain-with-www-at-the-same-time-or-at

Comment: this is, unfortunately, a feature of localstorage;  it is not an issue or a bug.

Comment: browser does not consider it *"same origin"*