# How to edit my code to save the same value of the domain.com to www.domain.com?

Tags: javascript

What I have below is a script that passes a variable from the crossvalue.html to an iframe crossvaluePOST.html and creates a localstorage to the (without www) domain.com

My question is how can I create the same localstorage value for the www.domain.com when domain.com/crossvalue.html (without www) runs?

**this is crossvalue.html**

```
<iframe id="da-iframe" src="crossvaluePOST.html"></iframe>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var iframeWin = document.getElementById("da-iframe").contentWindow; 

myMessage= Math.floor(Math.random()*801);
        iframeWin.postMessage(myMessage, "http://domain.com");
        return false;

};
</script>
```

**and this is the crossvaluePOST.html**

```
<script>

function displayMessage (evt) {
    var message;
    if (evt.origin !== "http://domain.com")  {
        message = "You are not worthy";
    }
    else {

        localStorage['abc'] =  evt.data;
    }   
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    // For standards-compliant web browsers
    window.addEventListener("message", displayMessage, false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", displayMessage);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The question is: "Why?" The correct way to handle this would be to always redirect `www.domain.com` to `domain.com` or the way round. Never copy content.

Comment: @JohannesH. I agree with you, but in this case it is something that  I do not have permissions since I provide other webpages with an external code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if the same origin policy lets you access local storage of other subdomains. I never tried this tbh, but one approach could be to try and load a javascript file from the www-prefixed domain to create the storage?

Comment: @JohannesH. what I follow is this logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains but I do not know if I am correct

Comment: I just read that post, actually. What you do is different. You need to load `www.domain.com/crossvaluePOST.html` on the non-prefixed site, and the way round.

Comment: @JohannesH. I think the solution you are suggesting is too simple that it messes with my head and it is annoyingly funny. Can you provide me with an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I try to avoid posting suggestions as answers unless I can confirm they actually work. But I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to "[use localStorage across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)" (which you linked yourself), the way to do this is to load a page from the other subdomain into your page, and communicate with that page to enter the values. This is necessary because of [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy): a script on a webpage is only allowed to access localstorage from the domain the site was loaded from.

In your case that means, that `domain.com/crossvaluePOST.html` cannot access the localstorage for `www.domain.com`, but only `domain.com`. TO change this, you need to load `www.domain.com/crossvaluePOST.html` in `domain.com/crossvalue.html` (and `domain.com/crossvaluePOST.html` in `www.domain.com/crossvalue.html` if you need both directions).

Just change your `crossvalue.html` to

```
<iframe id="da-iframe" src="//www.domain.com/crossvaluePOST.html"></iframe>

<script>
    // ...
</script>
```

to write the `www.domain.com` localstorage when the page is accessed using `domain.com` (if you need both directions, you obviously have to change the URL based on where the page is loaded from)

Disclaimer: this is just taken from the post you linked, I never tried this.