# Why localStorage returns null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, null

For example. I'm on facebook in console(chrome) and write this:

```
var txt = "some text"; 
localStorage.setItem("storage",txt);
```

Then i go on Twitter in console and write this:

```
var text = localStorage.getItem("storage");
alert(text);
```

Why it gives me null?

Comment: what does this mean? _i go on Twitter in console_

Comment: Because `localStorage` is domain specific. See [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `LocalStorage` context is *per domain*.

You can't save an item on one domain, i.e http://foo.com, then go to another domain http://bar.com and access it there.

If you `setItem()` within http://foo.com you can only `getItem()` within http://foo.com.

From [MDN - Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage):

> The Storage interface of the Web Storage API provides access to the session storage or local storage for **a particular domain**

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there an option to do that on different domains?

Comment: No, you can't do that, at least not in a straightforward way. There's some workarounds detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains) though.

Comment: I don't care that is Storage or something else. I just need to transport some text between two different pages.

Comment: That merits a whole new question on it's own

Comment: Okay. Thank you for help.

Comment: @Mimoid In general, different domains are not allowed to affect each other in any way, unless the scripts in the two domains have made special arrangements.

Comment: @Mimoid It's a security feature. If I go to your web site, I shouldn't have to worry that you've done something that will interfere with my Twitter experience.