# How to share LocalStorage between angular5 web app and VueJS2 web app

Tags: angular, local-storage, vuejs2

I have 2 web apps one is developed in angular5(is the standard ui in my site) and other in VueJS2(is the admin ui), both are subdomains of the same domain (site.com, admin.site.com), what I need is to share the user authentication data between them, this information currently I store in the browser using LocalStorage.

---

I have knowledge of this question: [4026479](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)

The accepted solution should work but its mostly a workaround. It doesn't  work like LocalStorage does, it's not so flexible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use localStorage across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)

Comment: I'm looking for something most like xdLocalStorage, but this one have not support for angular5.

Comment: Not possible to do that. It'd be a security issue: https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/548 You can still use cookies though.