# how to share the localstorage of Maindomain to subdomain in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, local-storage

is there a way in angular to automatically log-in user when he lands in subdomain. The user is already logged in maindomain and his token,user-info is set in localstorage but when he is redirected to subdomain i need access of maindomain in subdomain

say `example.com` is maindomain and `abc.example.com` is subdomain

Comment: Such questions are almost never framework-specific. This is general JS question that was answered a number of times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use localStorage across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)