# Do subdomains share local storage?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, local-storage

I'm currently building two react apps with both storing a redux state in local storage.

Will the example domains below share the same local storage?

1. www.website.com
2. admin.website..com

Due to the nature of the apps, I do not want their local storage to be shared and hoping this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Google "subdomain localstorage", the first result answers your question.

Comment: React here, https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/548

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-localstorage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is based on a Document's origin. For example, the origin of this page is:

```
self.origin; // "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

So, no, `localStorage` will not be shared across subdomains. If you did want to share `localStorage` across sub-domains, there is a solution [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains) for that :)

Comment: Looks like there are a few solutions if you need the cross domain support. I'll do some research on this when I need to that type of solution. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.