# How to share local storage across multiple web applications

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, local-storage

So I am working on an intranet web application that needs some information from another web application. So I planned to use local storage for this over passing through URL. So is there any way to achieve this? Both application is deployed in same domain eg: [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com).

1st one URL will be
[www.abcd.com/first](http://www.abcd.com/first)

2nd one will be
[www.abcd.com/second](http://www.abcd.com/second)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use localStorage across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a localStorage API if I were you, implementing the following functions:

- Get
- Set
- Clear

All the applications would communicate with this API, so, if one of your applications makes a change on the localStorage of a user and stores it in the API, then the API would be aware of that change upon starting from the next request from any other application.

I would also implement a client-side shared by all the applications you have which would handle the localStorage in the browser and would send requests to the API I have mentioned above.