# How to manage local storage for two different paths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

Web application under the Cypress test has local storage containing of 2 different parts and each part belongs to its own URL. I need to get and set local storage items in the both. How can I do that? E.g. `console.log(Cypress.LocalStorage);` command gives me an empty array which I believe belongs to the first part which is empty indeed. But another one is not empty. So how can I manage it (get/set items)? Here is an example for cookies: `$.cookie("LoginUser", selectedUser, { path: '/' });` But I was not able to rebuild it for local storage.

Comment: do you mean two different domain names?

Comment: Two different app paths like https://www.cypress.io/ and https://docs.cypress.io

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains answer your question?