# Allow parent domain to access local storage of subdomain

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my parent domain, e.g. `https://awesomedomain.com` which hosts the landing page for my app and the main app is hosted on `https://app.awesomedomain.com` .

When I authenticate a user on the subdomain `https://app.awesomedomain.com` and store the data in local storage I want the parent domain `https://awesomedomain.com` to be able to have access to the local storage of the subdomain.

Both apps are all on React. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This won't work due to security restrictions. Each subdomain has its own local-storage-object. You'll have to persist data yourself. Maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use localStorage across subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains)