# If I have www.domain.com store something in local storage, can my react app on app.domain.com access it?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I don't know how to test this locally.

Say I have a website at `www.domain.com` that stores something in localstorage. I have the web application at `app.domain.com`, can it access the item stored in localstorage by `www.domain.com`?

Is it accessible across subdomain?

Comment: No subdomain can not access to localstorage.You should use the cookies. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookies-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: I see you are new here. If you want your questions to be well-received and answered, you should try to follow the posting guidelines in this resource https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026479/use-localstorage-across-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately no you can't.

Local Storage is used per exact domain.

However, you can use cookies instead:

You can specify the cookie domain in your header

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=.mydomain.com
```

The leading '.' makes the cookie available for any subdomain.